# Как сделать такой треугольник на css?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  background: silver;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 115px solid white;
  border-left: 115px solid transparent;
  border-right: 115px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

пробывал так но угол слишком острый выходит

Comment: У вас написано все верно, просто нужно было поиграться с `border-top` - сделать меньше.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так

```css
.triangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #20a3bf;
  position: relative;
}

.triangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #20a3bf;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: достойный ответ

Answer (score 4):

```css
body {
  background: silver;
}

.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 39px solid white;
  border-left: 115px solid transparent;
  border-right: 115px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```